# How to move or copy a file/directory from my computer to ather computer?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I have a program in C# which i can move and copy files and directories by compress or by not compress between two path in a computer, but i want to do this between two computer. I want to use as target path of other computer's driver. How can i do this?

Thanks for your helps,

Comment: Nice example on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx also please read on how to use System.IO.File class at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a couple of ways you could do this,

- Setup a `FTP` Server on the other side using a FTP component
- Directly connect to the other machine using a `UNC` Path
- Use a `SCP` style system if the machine is a unix box
- Setup a file transfer protocol of your own (ie send a bytestream over the network).

I would strongly recommend using a pre-existing protocol though, such as FTP, that way you can re-use libraries and it promotes inter-op with other programs.

Comment: Please don't use FTP for anything.  It's a horrible protocol that doesn't play nicely with firewalls (PASV mode notwithstanding) and has no meaningful security.

Comment: SCP is definitely the best way forward but support is limited amogst the windows world :(